# I am trying to use a letter in a string

Tags: python

I'm trying to get an individual character in a string to then decode it.
I was thinking something like this:

```
N=0
message = ""

while n=!len(string):
    letter=Nth letter in string #This is the part I need help with
    num = ord(letter)
    result = num - shift_key
    message = message + result
    N = N + 1
print(message)
```

Comment: do you mean string[n] ?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Have you tried what you are proposing and it is not working? If yes, what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
message = ''.join(chr(ord(c) - shift_key) for c in string)
```

In any case, in order to access the 5th letter of a string, you can use `string[4]`. Example: `string = 'string'; print string[4] # prints 'n'`

There are a few things wrong with your code:

1. you used `n` instead of `N` in your while loop
2. `N != len(string)` instead of `N =! len(string)`
3. result is a number, you are adding it to the string message, which will raise an error. => message = message + chr(result)

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop and simply iterate over the string:

```
for letter in string:
    num = ord(letter)
    result =  (num - shift_key) % 255
    message += chr (result)  #call chr on result to get a string
```

Which would be the same as indexing the string with `N`:

```
N=0
message = ""

while N != len(string): # != not =! or use < len(string)
    letter=string[N] # This is the part I need help with
    num = ord(letter)
    result =  (num - shift_key) % 255
    message +=  chr(result)
    N += 1 # same as N = N + 1
print(message)
```

Just a lot easier.

```
In [20]: s = "foobar"

In [21]: for letter in s:
   ....:     print(letter)
   ....:     
f
o
o
b
a
r
```

You can put the code in a [list comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension):

```
 print("".join([chr((ord(letter) - shift_key) % 255) for letter in string]))
```

If you don't use `%` you can end up with a `ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)` when trying to conver result to a str.

Comment: in the OP's code, there are a few errors: n vs N, =! vs !=, ...